# How to extract the first float from a string in python

Tags: python

I have a string containing a string and word, I want to extract the first float the string.

```py
myString = 12.5% per month
myFloat= [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', myString )][0]
```

I want to have `12.5` as `myFloat`.

Thank you

Comment: `float(re.search(r"\b\d+\.\d+\b", myString).group(0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not change your code completly:

```
import re
myString = "12.5% 35.6 per month"

myFloat= [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+', myString )][0]
```

All I've changed is the regex expression to `r'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'`.

But, as Oliver pointed in his comment, you dont need to use `re.findall` to get the first occurrence.

You can simply: `myFloat= float(re.search(r'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+', myString).group(0))`

Comment: Why to use `re.findall()` and generate useless list if you need just first occurrence? And your expression is far from being perfect, try to launch this code with `myString = "12.5% 35.6 per month"`

Comment: @OlvinRoght you're right about de `re.findall()`, the thing is: as I said in the answer, I did the smallest code change possible in his own code (which was almost correct). And the example you provided works as expected, `myFloat` will be equals `12.5`, maybe you should test again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I copied wrong sample `myString = "a12/5% per month"`

Comment: @OlvinRoght you're right, I had a typo on my regex expression. I've forgot a \ before the `.` on the expression. I Will edit the answer.

Comment: Add also `\b` to not match smth like `1.2.3.4.5`.